# React Testing - TypeError: baseReducer is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm having some issues with unit tests (RTL). It's really quite bizarre. My tests were running fine, but then I modified my store.js, and then my App.test.js started failing, the rest kept passing... And then if I modified a test, it would fail (even if it was a dumb component) with the same error (TypeError: baseReducer is not a function). So I tried replicating it in codesandbox but I can't? If you look at the example in the codesandbox, it's pretty close to the production app setup.

So far I have tried:

1. Returning the appReducer instead of the root Reducer
2. Commenting out everything in the app reducer except 1 (tried each one)
3. Returning fooReducer and barReducer instead of the actual feature reducers in the application.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-help-basereducer-error-forked-p89dw

*The redux implementation works fine in browser*

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve is required by SO rules, otherwise the question is considered off-topic. That the demo is unable to reproduce the problem certainly doesn't help.

Comment: You may find with a bit of google magic that baseReducer belongs to redux-persist that wasn't mentioned in the question. The error means that a reducer you provided as persistReducer argument is not a function. If the only place it's used is `persistReducer(fooPersistConfig, fooReducer)` like in the demo, this means that fooReducer was imported incorrectly or so, although it would be much better if this were provided in the question because error message that you truncated most likely contains this information. Hope this helps, because currently you're the only person who can debug the problem